# using jQuery's .load() function to load multiple forms onto a page, and saving the filled in forms

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a page where I can input multiple "orders" on one "invoice". I have three types of orders and each type can be on the invoice multiple times. Right now I write a separate aspx page for each type of order. something like this:

order1.aspx, order2.aspx, order3.aspx are very similar to this:

```
<form id="order1" runat="server" class="order1">
    <asp:Label ID="lblOrder1" runat="server" for="txtOrder1"><b>From:</b></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" ID="txtOrder1" name="txtOrder1" class="order1"/>
</form>
```

On the main page, I can click one of 3 buttons to add an order type, with jQuery:

```
$('#btnOrder1').click(function () { $("#col3").append($("<div>").load("order1.aspx"));});
```

When I click the order button, it loads up the order form on the page. If I click it again, it loads another. This works fine.

When I click the save button on the invoice page, I need to fill the order objects(three objects, each representing a different type of order) with the values from the correct order and then save it to a database. I have the database saving code done, but I don't know how I can cycle through each order form on the page to fill in the appropriate object. I also need to be able to compare the different instances of each order, so I can check that the dates filled in on the order are not conflicting but I suspect I will be able to do this when I fill the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cycle is being messed due to the page-life cycle, and probably due to accesibility or events from objects appended to the DOM. (And probably due to multiple jquery functions and scripts loaded from each page).

Please, take a look at UserControls http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET

Instead of having one ASPX page for each type, you could have a "UserControl" per type.
After doing that, you could consider having only 1 usercontrol with some parameters to manage the OrderType.